# How to install cudatoolkit package on the WinPython distribution

Tags: python-3.7

How can I install the `cudatoolkit` package on the WinPython distribution? When I look at the list of unofficial binaries it's not there and when I do:

`python -m pip install cudatoolkit`

I get

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cudatoolkit (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cudatoolkit
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed this link and was able to install cudatoolskit for Winpython. I didn't have to add the path since it was automatically added to windows environment.

https://github.com/numba/conda-recipe-cudatoolkit/issues/17#issuecomment-533107631

After installation I ran the following code to see if my GPU is working

```
from numba import jit, cuda 
print(cuda.gpus)
```

If you get <Managed Device 0> that means your GPU is detected.

I used this replies example to test the GPU difference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384003/14689548

Comment: Doing that does not work for me and give me the same error in my question.