# Bounds checking is not supported for CUDA

Tags: python, python-3.x, jit, numba

I am trying to use Numba and access the GPU in order to accelerate the code, but I get the following error:

```
in jit raise NotImplementedError("bounds checking is not supported for CUDA")
NotImplementedError: bounds checking is not supported for CUDA
```

I saw that another question was raised, but not completely specified nor answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012614/notimplementederror-bounds-checking-is-not-supported-for-cuda). 
I implemented the 2-for loops when I saw that the vectorized code (`y = corr*x + np.sqrt(1.-corr**2)*z`) did not work (same error). I also tried to play around with the option `boundscheck`, but this did not change the outcome.
The error did not appear when not specifying the `target`, since it goes on the CPU automatically (I guess).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

N = int(1e8)
@jit(nopython=True, target='cuda', boundscheck=False)
def Brownian_motions(T, N, corr):
    x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(T,N))
    z = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(T,N))
    y = np.zeros(shape=(T,N))
    for i in range(T):
        for j in range(N):
            y[i,j] = corr*x[i,j] + np.sqrt(1.-corr**2)*z[i,j]
    return(x,y)

x, y = Brownian_motions(T = 500, N = N, corr = -0.45)
```

Could you please help me? Python is 3.7.6 and Numba is 0.48.0.

Comment: Cuda version is 10.2. On the other hand, if I try with `@vectorize(['UniTuple(float64, 2)(float64, float64, float64)'], target='cuda')` as decorator, the error I get is `Unknown attribute 'normal' of type Module`.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but target ='cuda' requires more code to initialize a kernel, send the data to the GPU. 
While we're here bounds check is fine here because you're initializing the arrays with the same shapes but be careful. You'll start getting funny outputs if arrays are different shapes

Answer (score 6):

In my case I also replaced with **@jit** which is decorator to compile the multiple operations using XLA. Here is an example code to see the performance of CPU and GPU.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np 
# to measure exec time 
from timeit import default_timer as timer    

# normal function to run on cpu 
def func(a):                                 
    for i in range(10000000): 
        a[i]+= 1      

# function optimized to run on gpu  
@jit
#(target ="cuda")                          
def func2(a): 
    for i in range(10000000): 
        a[i]+= 1
if __name__=="__main__": 
    n = 10000000                            
    a = np.ones(n, dtype = np.float64) 
    b = np.ones(n, dtype = np.float32) 

    start = timer() 
    func(a) 
    print("without GPU:", timer()-start)     

    start = timer() 
    func2(a) 
    print("with GPU:", timer()-start)
```

Result:
without GPU: 5.353004818000045
with GPU: 0.23115529000006063

Answer (score 2):

Replace @jit(nopython=True, target='cuda', boundscheck=False) with @jit

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

N = int(1e8)
@jit
def Brownian_motions(T, N, corr):
    x = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(T,N))
    z = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(T,N))
    y = np.zeros(shape=(T,N))
    for i in range(T):
        for j in range(N):
            y[i,j] = corr*x[i,j] + np.sqrt(1.-corr**2)*z[i,j]
    return(x,y)

x, y = Brownian_motions(T = 500, N = N, corr = -0.45)
```

Comment: Hi @Amit, thank you for the answer. The problem when I change the decorator with @jit is that I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Do you know by chance why this would be the case? Thanks in advance. The same if I just use @jit(nopython=True).